Windows 11 - opens multiple instances of some programs (like cmd)
When I run cmd and some other programs, it will open 2 (sometimes more) instances of it. This is regardless of whether I open it from a shortcut, the taskbar, or just typing 'cmd' into the Start Menu area.
This also seems to happen with other programs like ssh where I have some shortcuts. I run the shortcut, and it will also open an additional cmd window, and other times it just randomly opens duplicate ssh windows.
I have Visual Studio 2022 installed, and I first noticed this issue when debugging programs from VS, it would seem to open 3 or 4 console windows whenever I ran a program, it would just sit there asking to press ctrl-d, but the behaviour seems similar, so wonder if it's linked.
I'm considering a Windows re-install, but it seems a bit drastic.
